# Need a regex to match a variable length string of numbers that can't be all zeros

Tags: regex, validation, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I need to validate an input on a form. I'm expecting the input to be a number between 1 to 19 digits. The input can also start with zeros. However, I want to validate that they are not all zeros. I've got a regex that will ensure that the input is numeric and between 1 and 19 numbers.

```
^\d[1,19]$
```

But I can't figure out how to include a check that the entire string is not all zeros. I tried this

```
^(![0]{1,19})(\d[1,19])$
```

but it fails on 0000000000000000001 because it's allowing a variable number of zeros.

How do I check that the entire string is NOT zeros?

Thanks.

I'm trying to do this in a ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator so I was hoping for a single expression. I have other options, so I'm not out of luck if this can't be done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`^(?!0+$)\d{1,19}$`

Comment: I tried this one before and it doesn't work for the example I gave. Wasn't sure what the ? did though.

Comment: As codelogic says, it's a negative lookahead assertion.  It says "only match if what's ahead of me is something other than a bunch of zeroes followed by the end of the string".  Lookaheads are fairly strong magic. ;)

Comment: Lookbehinds too, for that matter.

Comment: This is starting to make sense but I'm still confused about the ? in the expression. What previous element is the ? referring to?

Comment: @Notorious2tall: Check out this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html .

Comment: It isn't.  It's part of a syntax completely separate from the meaning of ? that you're thinking of.  There's a whole set of PCRE syntax based around (? as the opener of a special sequence, starting with (?: for grouping without positional extraction.

Comment: Thanks, annakata.  I always value feedback from you because your username is made of awesome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just do a negative lookahead:

```
(?!^0+$)(^\d{1,19})
```

This works fine in Perl.

Comment: You should "factor out" the ^ and put it at the very beginning; your way will work, but this way expresses the intent more clearly. And you need to add a $ to the end so it can't match anything else after the digits.

Answer (score 2):

(?!0+$) is a lookahead directive.  The ?! is the negative lookahead command to search for 1 or more 0's to the end of the string.  If that matches, then the characters are consumed, leaving the regular digit search of \d{1,19}.

[Boost Perl Regexp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) has a good discussion of perl regexp as recognized by Boost.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need RegEx for that

```
            ulong test;
        string number = "1234567890123456789";
        if (ulong.TryParse(number, out test) && (test < 9999999999999999999ul) && (test > 0))
            Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Comment: I'm sure he knows how to make logic for it as a general case.  What he's trying to do is package it up as a RE, and we can assume he has reasons for doing that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I can validate it on the server side but wanted to do this with a RegExValidator. Partly b/c I don't want to make a post back and partly b/c I want to learn regex. Basically practical and selfish reasons. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with your platform, but if the designers of your RegExValidator were real smart, they may have made it so that you can both run it on server-side and render it as client-side script, which is highly optimal (you need it on client side too, but never ever trust a client).